# Action on cohomology groups using Poincare duality

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, poincare-duality

on the one hand it is clear, that for a degree $d$ map $f: \mathbb{P_\mathbb{C}}^1 \to \mathbb{P_\mathbb{C}}^1$ induces multiplication by $d$ on cohomology. On the other hand, if I use Poincare duality, I get a commutative diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H^2(\mathbb{P_\mathbb{C}}^1 )\ @>{f^\ast}>> H^2(\mathbb{P_\mathbb{C}}^1 )\\
@VVV @VVV\\
H_0(\mathbb{P_\mathbb{C}}^1 ) @<{f_\ast}<< H_0(\mathbb{P_\mathbb{C}}^1 )
\end{CD}

From this would follow, that $f^\ast$ is the identity, as $f_\ast$ is. How can I solve this contradiction?

Comment: You should only expect squares involving Poincare duality isomorphisms to commute if the relevant map is degree 1. In this case, the diagram would commute and there would be no contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P_C}^1}$ What makes you think this diagram commutes ?

Let's look at what it does: let $[\P]$ denote the characteristic class of $\P$. Then the vertical arrows are $x\mapsto [\P]\cap x$, so if you start in the top left hand corner, and follows right-down-left, you get $x\mapsto  f_*([\P]\cap f^*x)$, whereas if you just go down, you get $x\mapsto [\P]\cap x$.

But now, naturality of the cap-product means $f_*([\P]\cap f^*x)= f_*[\P] \cap x$ (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_product#Equations)).

Now these two maps have no reason to agree, and in fact $f_*[\P]=  d[\P]$, so they don't, unless $d =1$, which is what we would want

Comment: I misinterpreted "being compatible with orientations" and thought it was irrelevant as I consider complex manifolds, but clearly means, as you have pointed out, that the map has degree one.